# CECHO echoing a big ASCII art

Tags: batch-file, colors, echo, ascii-art

I went online and found a tool called `cecho` which is batch file's `echo` with color. I have a big piece of ASCII art(237 x 57 char) and I want to use `cecho` to color them.

As far as I know, I have to add `{color_code}` every time I want to change color. However, this method won't work for this big picture. Is there any way to simplify
the job?

[Here's the ASCII art,](http://pastebin.com/Jax04myj)

[and I hope there are some simple ways to make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8veBG.png)

Note: sorry for being a "write the code for me" guy, but I have totally no idea how to achieve this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ascii-art generated from pictures uses a lot of colors/shades (the simple hart from text-image.com has 219) A console has only a palette of 16 colors. So this ascii art isn't designed to be displayed in a console, I don't know of a program helping convert to this.

Comment: You're right..... I didn't notice this.....